# Modification in Java file, is it required to run ndk-build every time?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

i create one Project using NDK-sdk using eclipse, i change "c files inside jni folder" then i run ndk-build.

is it necessary to ndk-build after change in java file also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it goes, you compile only when you change code:

> - Any Change in C file -> ndk-build -> Re-compile the project so that library gets packaged with the APK -> Re-install on the phone

Any change in the Java File of the Project

> - Recompile the project -> Re-install on the phone

The shared object library file once generated need not be compiled till any code is modified.

Answer (score 1):

you need to re-build if you modified something in the c part, and if you modified in the jni java part (method definition as this requires modifying c part also)

Answer (score 1):

If you change the code into the c/c++ file then you will have to build that library using ndk-build. You do not have to build the library if you are not changing the c/c++ file.